# Laravel controller Single Responsibility principle

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method in Laravel controller. How can I improve this code? How can I implement single responsibilty here or maybe there are some other tips I can use in this code? I know that controller methods should be kept as small as possible,but I don't know if it's better idea to split this code in separate methods.

```
public function displayData(CityRequest $request)
    {
        if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($request->validator->messages());
        }
        else {
            $cityName = $request->city;
            $cityName = str_replace(' ','-',$cityName);
            $cityName = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $cityName);
            $response = $this->guzzle->request('GET', asset("/api/products/recommended/" . $cityName));
            $response_body = json_decode($response->getBody());
            if(isset($response_body->error))
            {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['city'=>$response_body->error]);
            }
            $city = $response_body->city;
            $condition = $response_body->current_weather;
            $products = $response_body->recommended_products;
            return back()->with(['city' => $city, 'condition' => $condition, 'products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some simple tips on how you can improve your code. There are still more you can do to improve it, but is a good start and it helps you get closer to the single responsibility principle.

- Move the API request to a service (`App\Services\ProductsApi\Client`).
- Move the formatting of city to a helper (`App\Helpers\Format`).
- Consider moving the formatting of city to `CityRequest` so the controller doesn't have to do it.
- No need for new variables, use the properties returned by `$response` instead.
- No need for `else`-statement, since the `if`-statement has `return`.

Your controller:

```
use App\Services\ProductsApi\Client;

public function __construct(Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
}

public function displayData(CityRequest $request)
{
    if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($request->validator->messages());
    }

    $response = $this->client->getRecommended(
        App\Helpers\Format::slugify($request->city)
    );

    if ($response->error) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
            'city' => $response->error
        ]);
    }

    return back()->with([
        'city' => $response->city ?? null, 
        'condition' => $response->current_weather ?? null,  
        'products' => $response->recommended_products ?? null, 
    ]);
}
```

Helper:

```
public static function slugify($value)
{
    return Illuminate\Support\Str::slug(
        iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $value),
        '-'
    );
}
```

(None of the code above is tested)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should extract the `else` body in a private methode. Don't forget to return the result of this methode or else the User won't be redirected:

```
else{
  return $this->getProducts()
}
```

Then you could split this methode even more and extract the `$cityName` valdidation. Also, you usually don't do API-requests in a Controller, but it depends on your project if you should extract the request in a seperate Model.

Overall, I've seen much more bloated controllers, even in professional environments.

Answer (score 1):

A typical controller does stuff like:

- Validate the incoming request
- Retrieve values from that request
- Serve a response

In your case the controller also does:

- Parsing of the request parameters
- Send API calls to an external endpoint
- Handle decoding and errors in external API calls

The last 3 can be split into a separate service (or even 3 separate services)